# SSL from personal machine for testing Progressive Web Apps

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, progressive-web-apps

I want to test building Progressive Web Apps and know this requires SSL. I am able to test onlocalhost (using npm http_server) but would like to test from other machines on the same local network and some mobile devices, so I need https and an SSL certificate.

I have tried using XAMPP on a windows machine, and made a certificate using makecert, but even though I installed it on Chrome on another machine, it didn't work.

Any ideas how I can achieve this ie run web server of some kind on one Windows 10 machine, host the pages using SSL and browse from another and mobile devices?

Do I have to use 3rd party certs, and would these work on a local machine (eg by local IP) rather than a domain name?

Bit confused!

Comment: It may be easier to just use a free HTTPS host like https://glitch.com/ for your testing.

Comment: Thanks, will investigate!